# Handlebars - "undefined" al mostrar información dentro de un #each

Tags: javascript, nodejs, handlebars.js

Cuando recorro un objeto, ejemplo

```js
{{#each personas}}
    <h1>{{nombre}}<h1>
{{/each}}
```

Funciona perfecto, pero si deseo agregar otra variable que no pertenezca al objeto que recorro, simplemente lo desconoce y me manda un "undefined"

```js
<p>{{data.info}}<p>   <!-- Me muestra la información correctamente --> 
{{#each personas}}
    <h1>{{nombre}}<h1>
    <p>{{data.info}}<p> <!-- Me muestra un "undefined"-->
{{/each}}
```

¿Cómo puedo renderizar esa variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa `{{../data.info}}`.

Al usar el *helper* `#each` se cambia el contexto sobre el cual se evalúan las expresiones. Al poner `../` al comienzo de la expresión se puede hacer referencia al contexto padre. Esto está explicado en [la documentación](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#changing-the-context) (inglés), de la cual traduzco este fragmento:

> ### Cambiando el contexto
>
> Algunos *helpers* como `#with` e `#each` te permiten adentrarte en objetos anidados. Cuando incluyes segmentos `../` en tu ruta, Handlebars cambiará al contexto padre.
>
> [...]
>
> #### Advertencia
>
> El valor exacto que `../` resolverá cambia dependiendo del *helper* que está llamando al bloque. Solo se necesita `../` si el contexto cambia. Los hijos de *helpers* como `{{#each}}` requerirán usar `../` mientras que los hijos de *helpers* como `{{#if}}` no.
>
> [...]
>
> Este comportamiento es nuevo en Handlebars 4; las notas de la publicación mencionan el comportamiento anterior así como también el plan de migración.